# What does "|" sign mean in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I often see something like that:
`something.property|escape`

---

`something` is an object, `property` is it's string property. `escape` - i don't know :)

What does this mean? And what min python version it is used in?

EDIT: The question was asked wrongly, it said "What does | mean in Python", so the bitwise or answers are correct, but irrelevant, please do not downvote them

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more context than just the expression.  This is an operator that can be overloaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

obj.property|escape is the way to apply the [escape filter in a template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference), which will HTML escape the string representation of that property.

Comment: so, something.property|escape == escape(something.property) ?

Comment: Hmm - glad this answer helped, but technically this isn't python.

Comment: Dima, only in a template. And equal only in the semantic sense, I'm not sure (may be possible, because my Django is rusty) you can actually write it like "escape(something.property)".

Comment: Please be more careful when editing the question — a lot of the answers to the original question ("…mean in Python") are getting downvoted because they no longer look relevant.

Comment: No, you can't rewrite it in a function-calling style in a Django template.  You must use the pipe.  Django templates != Python code.  And you can't just use any Python function this way, it has to be registered as a template filter in a template library loaded in that template.

Comment: The correct name for it is "built-in template filter". It is not equivalent to a function call. But you can sort of understand it this way. The big difference is that you have to use the list of filters django provide and use the syntax defined by django. I don't count customised filter. That will be another story

Answer (score 14):

The pipe character indicates that you want to send the results of the left hand side to the filter defined on the right side.  The filter will modify the value in some way.

The 'escape' filter is just one of many.

The list of built in filters can be found here: 
[Django Documentation - Built-in filters reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference)

In a django template the | character definitely does not mean the 'bitwise OR' operator.

Comment: "definitely does not mean 'bitwise OR'".  Thanks for this clarity

Answer (score -3):

It's a bitwise "or".  It means escape if the property doesn't exist/is null.

Comment: Paul, the logical "or" operator is written "or". "|" is bitwise