# What does the “|” sign mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-rules

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417265/what-does-sign-mean-in-django) originally asked (wrongly) what does "|" mean in Python, when the actual question was about Django. That question had a wonderful answer by Triptych I want to preserve.

Comment: Nice try, but when you make the post CW, all the responses are CW as well.

Comment: The community wiki checkbox is marked by default, you can deselect it to have a non community wiki answer

Comment: This just shouldn't be a CW post.  It's not a "real" question because Vinko probably already knows the answer.  But it's still real in that it's about programming and people can google for it and such.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't want to let your answer go to waste

Comment: Thanks.   I was a little annoyed, honestly, that a decent answer would go to waste because a question was improperly phrased.  Interesting, the sort of problems that crop up as we trailblaze the wiki Q&A space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pipe character in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python)

Comment: @Pureferret: this is a more general question than the other, which is only about us as bitwise OR operator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Python, the `'|'` operator is defined by default on integer types and set types.

If the two operands are integers, then it will perform a [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR), which is a mathematical operation.

If the two operands are `set` types, the `'|'` operator will return the union of two sets.

```
a = set([1,2,3])
b = set([2,3,4])
c = a|b  # = set([1,2,3,4])
```

Additionally, authors may define operator behavior for custom types, so if `something.property` is a user-defined object, you should check that class definition for an `__or__()` method, which will then define the behavior in  your code sample.

So, it's impossible to give you a precise answer without knowing the data types for the two operands, but *usually* it will be a bitwise or.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise OR

Answer (score 0):

It could also be "tricked" into a pipe like in unix shells, see here http://code.google.com/p/python-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

**New In Python 3.9 - `dict` also supports the `|` operator**

[Full details in PEP 584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/)

Demo:

```
a: dict = {"arms": 2}
b: dict = {"legs": 2}
c = a | b
print(c)
```

Prints:

```
{'arms': 2, 'legs': 2}
```