# Pipe character in Python

Tags: python, pipe, bitwise-operators

I see a "pipe" character (`|`) used in a function call:

```
res = c1.create(go, come, swim, "", startTime, endTime, "OK", ax|bx)
```

What is the meaning of the pipe in `ax|bx`?

Comment: this should be interesting to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252585/functional-pipes-in-python-like-from-dplyr

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It is a *bitwise OR* of integers. For example, if one or both of `ax` or `bx` are `1`, this evaluates to `1`, otherwise to `0`. It also works on other integers, for example `15 | 128 = 143`, i.e. `00001111 | 10000000 = 10001111` in binary.

Comment: How about when I type 5|7 in the shell? It returns 7. why?

Comment: Because that's what bitwise OR does.

Comment: `5 = 101`, `7 = 111`, `101 | 111 = 111 = 7`

Comment: @Ignacio: Python does not have a logical or operator?! What do you call [`or`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), then?

Comment: @Ignacio are you referring to it as a null coalescing operator (like in C#/Perl)? Never heard of it referred to that way, but if I understand correctly, that does make sense in a way since it's a short-circuit operator. Is that what you were referring to (do I understand you properly)?

Comment: @zeekay: Correct. Rather than always returning `True` or `False`, `and` and `or` always return one of their operands, hence "coalescing" rather than "logical".

Comment: It's not strictly bitwise.  `(True | False) is True` whereas `(True | 0) is not True`.  There are different overloadings of `|` in python 2.6 depending on whether the arguments are the special integral values `(True, False)` vs regular integral values.

Comment: What Mike said. More generally, it calls the `__or__` method of the first operand with the second operand, so you can define its behavior for your own classes.

Answer (score 206):

This is also the union set operator

```
set([1,2]) | set([2,3])
```

This will result in `set([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: This is likely *much* more common that bitwise operations.

Comment: Hmm. Pardon @jpmc26 ‍♀️ Sets have explicit counterpart methods that should be favored. In the codebase I'm dealing with this is used rather exclusively for bit ops.

Answer (score 36):

In [Python 3.9 - PEP 584 - Add Union Operators To dict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) in the section titled **Specification**, the operator is explained.
The pipe was enhanced to merge (union) dictionaries.

```
>>> d = {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 3}
>>> e = {'cheese': 4, 'nut': 5}
>>> d | e
{'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 4, 'nut': 5} # comment 1
>>> e | d
{'cheese': 3, 'nut': 5, 'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2} # comment 2
```

**comment 1** If a key appears in both operands, the last-seen value (i.e. that from the right-hand operand) wins --> 'cheese': 4 instead of 'cheese': 3

**comment 2** cheese appears twice, the second value is selected so `d[cheese]=3`

Comment: I came across with an import statement from SqlAlchemy: S = Session | scoped_session. which suggest it is even works with classes as well

Answer (score 34):

Yep, all answers above are correct.

Although you could find more exotic use cases for "|", if it is an overloaded operator used by a class, for example,

https://github.com/twitter/pycascading/wiki#pycascading

```
input = flow.source(Hfs(TextLine(), 'input_file.txt'))
output = flow.sink(Hfs(TextDelimited(), 'output_folder'))

input | map_replace(split_words, 'word') | group_by('word', native.count()) | output
```

In this specific use case pipe "|" operator can be better thought as a unix pipe operator. But I agree, bit-wise operator and union set operator are much more common use cases for "|" in Python.

Answer (score 14):

[Bitwise OR](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

Answer (score 8):

It is a bitwise-or.

The documentation for all operators in Python can be found in the [Index - Symbols](http://docs.python.org/genindex-Symbols) page of the Python documentation.

Answer (score 8):

*Summarizing & extending previous answers:*

The **`|` operator originally does [bitwise OR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=bitwise%20operator#binary-bitwise-operations)**. Here is a [tutorial on bitwise operations](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#bitwise-or).

```py
f'{0b1100 | 0b1010 :04b}' == '1110'
```

On the other hand, Python operators can be overloaded by overloading their equivalent [operator functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). In particular, **`|` can be overloaded by implementing the function [`__or__` (and `__ror__`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211477/what-is-the-purpose-of-pythons-built-in-bool-method-ror)**. Any Python library, standard or userbase, can overload any operator (e.g., archived [PyCascading](https://github.com/twitter-archive/pycascading/wiki#pycascading)).

The Python built-in types such as **[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) overload `|`** to define union and merge, respectively. In particular, [Python 3.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/), [PEP 584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/), brought the overloaded `|` and other operators to `dict` and other standard library types.

```py
# sets; | does union of sets
#  the order does not matter, i.e., the operation is commutative
{1, 2} | {2, 3} == {1, 2, 3}

{2, 3} | {1, 2} == {1, 2, 3}


# dicts; | does "merging" of dicts
#   the order does matter, i.e., the operation is NOT commutative
{'a': 1, 'b': 2} | {'b': 99, 'c': 3} == {'a': 1, 'b': 99, 'c': 3}

{'b': 99, 'c': 3} | {'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Likewise, the [**`types.UnionType`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.UnionType), [introduced with Python 3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/), also overloads the binary-or operator `|`, in this case to signify a [union of types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) for type annotations/hints, e.g., `typing.Union[int, str] == int | str`.

A recent, popular overloading and usage of the `|` operator is in the Python [**LangChain** library](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart#prompttemplate--llm--outputparser) to [chain/pipe operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). This is the [exact code for how LangChain overloads the operator](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.0.295/libs/langchain/langchain/schema/runnable/base.py#L68-L86).

```py
# LangChain chained sequence of components
chain = prompt | model | output_parser
```

Comment: +1 for langchain, i was trying to figure out how exactly it uses pipe operator and missed that runnable thing

Comment: This is the best explanation of how langchain performs its 'magic' on the internet. Great comment, thank you.

Comment: Excellent answer, I've been looking for a deeper explanation of | operator overloading, and this is exactly what I've been looking for. Let's make writing pipelines and chains in Python a breeze!

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically in function call but regarding OPs headline one might nowadays also list the pipe operator for "**or**" functionality in **typing annotations**!

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

For example:

```py
def get_string_length(string: str | None = None) -> int:
    if string is None:
        string = 'muppets'
    return len(string)
```