# How to create a Python nested generator pipeline without a function call?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, python-3.8

I have the following snippet of code.

```py
x = (w for w in words if len(w) == 5)

def mk_gen(x, idx, val):
    return (w for w in x if w[idx] == val)

pattern = 'he_l_'
for idx, val in enumerate(pattern):
    if val == '_':
        continue
    x = mk_gen(x, idx, val) # Method 1
    # x = (w for w in x if w[idx] == val) # Method 2

print((list(x)))
# Method 1 -> ['heald', 'heals', 'heels', 'heild', 'heily', 'heils', 'helly', 'hello', 'hells', 'herls']
# Method 2 -> []
```

Words here is a list of English dictionary words.

Method 1 gives the expected output.

Method 2 however does not despite the fact that Method 1 is doing the same as Method 2 but calls a function that returns it rather than directly assigning the new generator.

Why does this happen?

I tried another way of making a new generator, using function call.

```py
def mk_gen_1(x, idx, val):
    for w in x:
        if w[idx] == val:
            yield w
```

This one also worked but the original Method 2 doesn't.

Another which I found in [Pythonic way to chain python generator function to form a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755702/pythonic-way-to-chain-python-generator-function-to-form-a-pipeline) doesn't work.

```py
gen_2_steps = [(lambda g:(w for w in g if w[idx] == val)) for idx, val in enumerate(pattern) if val != '_']
x = reduce(lambda g, f: f(g), [x, *gen_2_steps]) # Method 3
print(list(x))
```

This one works, but it is not what I intend to do. I intend to create generators by using a for loop and without calling another function.

```py
# Works
f2_1 = lambda g:(w for w in g if w[0] == 'h')
x = f2_1(x)
f2_2 = lambda g:(w for w in g if w[1] == 'e')
x = f2_2(x)
f2_3 = lambda g:(w for w in g if w[3] == 'l')
x = f2_3(x)
print(len(list(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different sets of variables used by Methods 1 and 2.

Method 1 uses the local names `idx` and `val` defined by `mk_gen`; it basically defines a closure, where the values passed to `mk_gen` are remembered by the generator even after `mk_gen` returns.

Method 2 uses the names `idx` and `val` that are defined (and redefined) by the `for` loop, because the generator expression is in the same scope as those variables.

Comment: I tried using a pattern with the last character as 's'; with Method 1, all the selected words ended with 's'. Thanks, @chepner, for such a precise and valid answer.