# Ensuring values in matrix are between a set range?

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R and I am working on function to manipulate a set of data.

I have a 20 by 5 matrix of values, to that I add a random number between -1 to 1. How can I ensure that all the values in the matrix stay between 0-10 in an efficient and fast manner (without using a loop to check a single value at a time).

These are the rules:

- If a value is greater than 10, change it to 10
- If a value is less
  thatn 0, change it to 0

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
m[] <- pmax(0,pmin(10,m))
```

The `m[]` on the lefthand side (rather than `m`) ensures that the matrix keeps its structure.

Here's a (probably unnecessary) example:

```
lwr <- 0; upr <- 10
set.seed(101)
mRaw <- matrix(runif(100, lwr, upr), nrow=20) 
m1 <- sample(c(-1,1),size=100,replace=TRUE)
mAdded <- m1 + mRaw
```

Now clamp:

```
mAdded[] <- pmax(lwr,pmin(upr,mAdded))
str(mAdded)
## still a matrix: num [1:20, 1:5] 2.72 0 6.1 7.58 3.5 ...
range(mAdded)  ## 0 10
```

Comment: `matrix(sample(c(-1,1),size=100,replace=TRUE),nrow=20)` might be a little more straightforward

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker. :-) Improved code:`library(dplyr)`

`mRaw <- runif(100, 0, 10) %>% as.integer %>% matrix(nrow = 20, ncol = 5)`
`m1 <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1),size=100,replace=TRUE),nrow=20)`
`mAdded <- m1 + mRaw`
`mAdded[] <- pmax(0,pmin(10,mAdded))`

Comment: I don't mind pipes in their place, but they don't seem to add much value here ...

Comment: I come from a pythonic land. I write in dplyr. :-D

Comment: huh, I don't think of pipes as pythonic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252585/functional-pipes-in-python-like-from-dplyr -- at least seems `pandas`-specific ? (and I think I prefer `x %>% fun1() %>%  fun2()` to `x.pipe(fun1).pipe(fun2)` anyway ...)

Comment: More about the code being tall and thin, and as readable as Robert Frost.

Comment: Variant: Matroyshka Doll. `mAdded[] <- pmax(0, pmin(10, matrix(as.integer(runif(100, 0, 10)), nrow = 20, ncol = 5) + matrix(sample(c(-1,1),size=100,replace=TRUE),nrow=20)))`  Maybe some folks prefer this, but to me it reads like Henry James.