# How can I use last variable executed in line? Like %>% in R (Python)

Tags: python, r, variables, pipe

I'm new in Python and I wonder if there is a way to use the last execution in the same code line. In R you can do that with pipes (%>%).

For example:

In R you can do this:

```
list(filter(lambda x: '_LI' not in x,BI.columns))) %>% list(filter(lambda x: '_LS' not in x,.)
```

that is the same as:

```
list(filter(lambda x: '_LS' not in x,list(filter(lambda x: '_LI' not in x,BI.columns))))
```

That last one works fine in Python but I like more the first way and  I want to do the same in Python. Is it possible?

Comment: No, Python doesn't have anything like this unfortunately. I believe there's libraries that *slightly* emulate it by using bitwise operators and wrapper classes, but they aren't great.

Comment: Maybe `list(filter(lambda x: '_LI' not in x,BI.columns)); list(filter(lambda x: '_LS' not in x,_))`?

Comment: @superbrain Although that only works in a REPL.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's actually half the reason I said "maybe" :-) The other half being that my REPL shows both lists and I'm not sure that's desired. Both issues can of course be overcome by explicitly assigning the first result to a variable. Not sure why they're not just doing that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252585/functional-pipes-in-python-like-from-rs-magritrr may be helpful - the answers have some packages that do similar things in Python.