# regular expression in python about or

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I know `p=re.compile('aaa|bbb')` can work, but I want to rewrite `p = re.compile('aaa|bbb')` using variables, something like

```
A = 'aaa'
B = 'bbb'
p = re.compile(A|B)
```

but this doesn't work. How can I rewrite this so that variables are used (and it works)?

Answer (score 5):

> `p=re.compile(A|B)`

*You are not doing the string concatenation correctly*. What you are doing is applying the ["bitwise or" (the pipe) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python) to strings, which, of course, fails:

```
>>> 'aaa' | 'bbb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Instead, you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
p = re.compile(r"|".join([A, B]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = 'aaa'
>>> B = 'bbb' 
>>> r"|".join([A, B])
'aaa|bbb'
```

And, make sure you trust the source of `A` and `B` (beware of [Regex injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)), or/and properly [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) them.

Comment: Python already provides a function to escape them, namely, [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape). So to make an alternation of an arbitrary set of literal strings, you'd just do: `r'|'.join(map(re.escape, literals_to_alternate_on))`.