# Allow user to add their own tasks (items) to a QListWidget in PyQt6/Qt designer

Tags: python, pyqt6, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I know how to add items to the list widget if you enter the items into an array, however I want to be able to edit the list widget in the user interface, to be able to add your own task to the widget from a user input without having to create a dialog to capture the inputs.

[image]

By pressing add tasks, I want to be able to add a task to the QListWidget without hard coding them in. Is there a way to do this?

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("main.ui", self)
        self.calendarWidget.selectionChanged(self.new_day_selected)
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add_task)
        self.editButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_task)
      
        tasks = [] #array to store items

    def new_day_selected(self, checked):
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPy()
        print("Date Changed: " + dateSelected)
    
    def add_task(self, checked):
        pass
    def edit_task(self, checked):
        pass
```

Comment: What are these tasks? Are they strings?

Comment: yes, things like homework

Comment: You can just make the listwidget editable. You won't need the buttons. Just add and edit the text straight in the view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962839/how-to-make-qlistwidget-items-editable

Comment: oh, is that using QList View? I was using QList Widget, ty

Comment: The linked question is about listwidgets, not about listviews.

Comment: [`addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#addItem)