# Logic code in python giving the wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x, logic

Given a day of the week encoded as 0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat, and a boolean indicating if we are on vacation, return a string of the form "7:00" indicating when the alarm clock should ring. Weekdays, the alarm should be "7:00" and on the weekend it should be "10:00". Unless we are on vacation -- then on weekdays it should be "10:00" and weekends it should be "off".

My code:

```
  def alarm_clock(day,vacation):
  if(vacation):
      if(day == 0 | day == 6):
          return "off"
      return "10:00"
  else:
      if(day == 0 | day == 6):
          return "10:00"
      return "7:00"
```

With input:

```
print(alarm_clock(0,True))
```

My code returns '10:00' when it should be 'off'

With input:

```
print(alarm_clock(0,False))
```

My code returns '7:00', it should be '10:00'

Where is the bug in my code?

Comment: `if(day == 0 or day == 6):` ? in python use `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
def alarm_clock(day,vacation):
    if(vacation):
        if(day == 0 or day == 6):
            return "off"
        return "10:00"
    else:
        if(day == 0 or day == 6):
            return "10:00"
        return "7:00"

print(alarm_clock(0,True))
```

results:

```
off
```

The pipe isn't doing what you'd expect: [Pipe character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python) it is in fact a bitwise operator.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm), the `logical "or" operator` in Python is `or`, not `|` which is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bitwise or "|". You need to use a logical or "or"

```
def alarm_clock(day,vacation):
  if(vacation):
      if(day == 0 or day == 6):
          return "off"
      return "10:00"
  else:
      if(day == 0 or day == 6):
          return "10:00"
      return "7:00"
```